# How do I iterate over all created yet unsaved objects of a particular class with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to create multiple instances of a class without saving them to a database. Then I want to loop through all the objects that I've created.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `.new` and put them in a collection? Without any context, it's difficult to see what the issue is.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, I'll work on both of those.

Comment: Ok, could you give me an example of accessing the objects as a group, of which I've created but not yet saved?

Comment: `foos = [ Foo.new, Foo.new, Foo.new ]; foos.each { |foo| puts foo }`

Comment: Hmmm, I guess is really about populating the [ Foo.new, Foo.new, Foo.new ]  I would do this with a Foo.all or something if I was using active record.  Is there a similar way to access all the objects that have not yet been saved?

Comment: And Dave, thanks for sticking with me here ;)

Comment: You have to create the objects somewhere; how are you creating them? `Foo.all` retrieves; `Foo.new` creates-but-doesn't-save. Without knowing how/when/where the objects are being created it's difficult to know the "best" way to put them in a collection. There could be a class variable collection, or you could use a factory method that saves them in a collection, or...

Comment: Yes, basically I would like them to be in a collection in memory, that doesn't require a database to be running.  And then I would like to be able to find all of the objects in that collection.

Comment: I understand--that's what the ideas above would do. Create them, add them to an array.

Comment: That is what I think I will end up doing.  Thank you for talking me through this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`ObjectSpace.each_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object):

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(YourClass) do |o|
  # Do something interesting with object 'o' here
end
```

If you can manually keep track of your objects then I think that would be better, I tend to see `ObjectSpace` as a last resort.